# Is `getopts` only useful when all options are provided upfront?

Tags: bash, getopts

I'm trying to see whether I can use `getopts` for my Bash script. However, I'm not sure what's wrong:

```
#! /bin/bash

while getopts "a:b" opt ; do
    case $opt in
        a)
            A_OPTION="option a was given argument $OPTARG"
            ;;
        b)
            B_OPTION="option b was found"
            ;;
    esac
done
if [ -n "$A_OPTION" ] ; then echo $A_OPTION ; fi
if [ -n "$B_OPTION" ] ; then echo $B_OPTION ; fi
shift $((OPTIND - 1))
echo "The remaining arguments are: $@"
```

The output is:

```
$ ./getopts-test foo goo -a moo -b
The remaining arguments are: foo goo -a moo -b
$ ./getopts-test -a moo -b foo goo
option a was given argument moo
option b was found
The remaining arguments are: foo goo
$ ./getopts-test -a moo foo goo -b
option a was given argument moo
The remaining arguments are: foo goo -b
$ ./getopts-test -b foo goo -a moo
option b was found
The remaining arguments are: foo goo -a moo
```

Why doesn't the script detect the options in all the cases? Is `getopts` only useful when the options are all provided upfront and not mixed with other arguments?

Answer (score 1):

(this is too long to be a comment and too poor to be an answer)

`getopt` try to detect single letter option with `-` (minus sign), and option with argument.

It stop when there is no (no more) option (no `-b`, no `-a foo`). It doesn't parse the full list.

So answer to second question is yes.

You might whish to write a getopt parser yourself and deal with this question are `-foo`  `--bar` arguements (e.g. a file, a string) or an option.

for a long time tradition was to put options first, argument later, precisely so you knew when option stop, and if `-foo` was an actual filename.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the manpage, it is expected behavior. `getopts` supports "options" and "option-arguments".

Guideline 4: all options should be preceded by `-`. That being said, `./getopts-test foo goo -a moo -b` will not work as "foo" is not an option nor an option-argument. Hence, it will stop.

An option-argument is specified by ":". In your definition, `a:` is an option-argument and it parses `-a moo` and `b` is just and option that parses `-b` in `./getopts-test -a moo -b foo goo`. The rest (`foo goo`) is just remaining.

Guideline 8: all arguments for an option-argument should be presented as one comma-separated. That's why `./getopts-test -a moo foo goo -b` just parses `-a moo`. The correct way is `./getopts-test -a moo,foo,goo -b`. (same applies to your last case)

Reference:

- https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getopts.html
- https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02